# Probability that a set of sample maps to another set of sample?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am recently reading a research paper and I came across author's calculation that I am not able to figure out:

There is a flow(sequence) of packets and n total buckets. All the balls in a flow are uniformly assigned to m random buckets, where m << n.

> What is a probability that 2 flows of packets will be assigned the same set of m buckets?

My solution: I consider this problem as picking m random samples from total of n. There are nCm ways to pick m buckets and only one of them will be similar so `1/nCm`.

Paper's answer: `m!/n^m`

Comment: Are buckets and packets different and identical?

Comment: packets are different than buckets... packets are like balls that are assigned to m random buckets... each flow can have many packets

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't understand the question, but I suspect the paper gives an asymptotic answer as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a flow of $n$ packets, and we have $m$ buckets.

- **The packets are identical, and buckets are identical.** In this case, there are $\big(n+(m-1)\big)!$ different ways that we can distribute $n$ different packets to $m$ different buckets. (Suppose we have $\underbrace{**\dots*}_{n}$, and we have $\underbrace{||\dots|}_{m-1}$. The stars are balls, and the lines are buckets. Why we have $m-1$ lines? For this question, consider this example. For three balls and two buckets, we have $***|$ (all balls are in the first bucket), $**|*$ (two balls are in the first bucket and one ball are in the second buckets),... Thus, we need $m-1$ lines.) If we have two flows, then the probability of the two flows be same is $\frac{1}{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}$.
- **The packets are *not* identical, and buckets are identical.** In this case, there are $\frac{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}{n!}$ different ways that we can distribute $n$ same packets to $m$ different buckets. If we have two flows, then the probability of the two flows be same is $\frac{n!}{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}$.
- **The packets are identical, and buckets are *not* identical.** In this case, there are $\frac{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}{(m-1)!}$ different ways that we can distribute $n$ different packets to $m$ same buckets. If we have two flows, then the probability of the two flows be same is $\frac{(m-1)!}{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}$.
- **The packets are *not* identical, and buckets are *not* identical.** In this case, there are $\frac{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}{n!(m-1)!}$ different ways that we can distribute $n$ same packets to $m$ same buckets. If we have two flows, then the probability of the two flows be same is $\frac{n!(m-1)!}{\big(n+(m-1)\big)!}$.